# Backtrack values in R for a logic

Tags: r

My request is slightly complicated.

Below is how my data looks like.

```
   **S.no      Date     City Sales  diff Indicator
1     1  1/1/2017 New York  2795     0         0
2     2 1/31/2017 New York  4248  1453         0
3     3  3/2/2017 New York  1330 -2918         1
4     4  4/1/2017 New York  3535  2205         0
5     5  5/1/2017 New York  4330   795         0
6     6 5/31/2017 New York  3360  -970         1
7     7 6/30/2017 New York  2238 -1122         1
8     8  1/1/2017    Paris  1451     0         0
9     9 1/31/2017    Paris  2339   888         0
10   10  3/2/2017    Paris  2029  -310         1
11   11  4/1/2017    Paris  1850  -179         1
12   12  5/1/2017    Paris  2800   950         1
13   13 5/31/2017    Paris  1986  -814         0
14   14 6/30/2017    Paris  3776  1790         0
15   15  1/1/2017   London  1646     0         0
16   16 1/31/2017   London  3575  1929         0
17   17  3/2/2017   London  1161 -2414         1
18   18  4/1/2017   London  1766   605         0
19   19  5/1/2017   London  2799  1033         0
20   20 5/31/2017   London  2761   -38         1
21   21 6/30/2017   London  1048 -1713         1**
```

diff is Current Month Sales-Last Month Sales, for each group, and Indicator is when diff is negative or positive.

I want to compute a logic for each group starting from last row to first row, aka in reverse order.

I want to see in reverse order, the value of Sales when indicator was 1. The compare that captured Sales value to the threshold value(2000), for next steps.

**Now below are two cases of comparison(Capture Sales v/s Threshold).**
 a. If captured value of sales, when Indicator is first 1(starting from last row to 1st row), is less than 2000, then store the captured values in a new dataset for each group.

b. If the captured of sales, when Indicator is first 1(starting from last row to 1st row), is greater than 2000, then skip that Indicator=1 row and move to the next row where Indicator=1, and repeat the same step for pt.a) and pt. b)

I want to bring the result in a new dataset, that will have a single row for each City providing me the "Sales value" for the aforementioned logic, along with the Date.

I simply want to understand how can i bring up this logic in R. Will rle function help?

```
Result:
S.no   Date    City    Value(Sales)
3.  3/2/2017  New York   1330
11. 4/1/2017  Paris      1850
21. 6/30/2017 London     1048
```

Thanks,
J

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected outout (e.g. for New York)?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with expected result and updated threshold value(2000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your data is already arranged it ascending order, you can do the following with base R:

```
threshold <-  2000

my_new_df <- my_df[my_df$Indicator == 1 & my_df$Sales < threshold, ]
my_new_df

#    S.no       Date     City Sales  diff Indicator
# 3     3 2017-03-02 New York  1330 -2918         1
# 11   11 2017-04-01    Paris  1850  -179         1
# 17   17 2017-03-02   London  1161 -2414         1
# 21   21 2017-06-30   London  1048 -1713         1
```

Now we have all rows where the Indicator is equal to one and the Salse value less than our threshold. But London has to rows and we only wnat the last one:

```
my_new_df <- my_new_df[!duplicated(my_new_df$City, fromLast = T),
                       c("S.no", "Date", "City", "Sales")]
my_new_df
#    S.no       Date     City Sales
# 3     3 2017-03-02 New York  1330
# 11   11 2017-04-01    Paris  1850
# 21   21 2017-06-30   London  1048
```

With the `fromLast`-argument in the `duplicated`, we start in the last row to check, whether the City has already been in the data set.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, but I am new to stack overflow

Comment: You click on the checkmar below the arrows on the left side. You should consider to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)